# Some problems with js in IE

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

With ASP.NET and Devexpress Combobox control on page generates js. 
This js perfect works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari. But it don't work in IE8. There is an interesting issue with this situation:

When in IE8 and developer toolbar is on, than it's works fine. But if I close dev toolbar, then occurs error 800a025e.

UPD:
I did not write js. It generates automatically. I simple write

```
ComboBox.Focus();
```

That's all.

Comment: What is your code? What is your error code? Be specific.

Comment: You should give your combo box Id a proper Id, not the name of the control itself...

Comment: Phill, please read attentively. I use devexpress control, which classname is **ASPxComboBox**, not ComboBox. In example can be ComboBox1, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might appear because you are using a version of DevExpress controls which are not compatible with IE 8.  Can you check how your code works with the latest (11.1.7) version?  Also, from your code, I suspect that the ComboBox is the value of the ASPxComboBox's ClientInstanceName property.  Right?

Comment: My version devexpress is 8. I can't install more newer. "ComboBox" is ID and ClientInstanceName of ASPxComboBox

Comment: IE8 is supported starting from DXperience 2009 vol 2: http://devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/WhatsNew2009v2/index.xml?page=28.  You should install a newer version to resolve this problem.